# Add .jar file into Tibco Designer

Tags: java, tibco

I want to use my class methods into TIBCO Designer(5.6) project. I export my Java project into .jar with my Eclipse Indigo. Then I create AliasLibrary in the Desinger and add the .jar. But after I create Java Method add click to choose Class, I click on my .jar file in **Class Path Archive List** field and **Package / Class list** is empty. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried adding the jar to your class path? You shouldn't need to from memory, but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

Try compiling it to the same target Java version as TIBCO Designer/BW is using. Usually TIBCO will use its own JRE, not necessarily the latest/the one you've installed if e.g. you've installed the JDK.